# Subscribe to URL change except addition/change of fragments in Angular

Tags: angular

What is the best way to know that your URL changed but also disregarding the addition/change of fragments?

I tried to subscribe to route events but the properties url and urlAfterRedirects are the same. I can create a variable that stores the previous URL and compare it with the current one but I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: If you are comfortable with rxjs, then you can try `pairwise()`. it will hold the last two changes of route url events emitted.

Comment: thanks that's a good use of rxjs ops

Comment: I have added a small [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-activatedroute-state-changes). Hope its helpful for others